# php variable that is a multiple of 3, starting at 2

Tags: php

I'm trying to add classes to the fist and the third columns of a page. Column1 is 'alpha' column three is 'omega' --> i have the code for adding it to the fist column.

using a variable(counter) starting at (and including) 0, every 3rd item after that gets 'alpha' but how do i write:

after ( and including ) $myNumber = 2, 5, 8... echo omega ??

```
$myNumber = 0
// Earlier in document

if ($myNumber % 3 == 0 || $myNumber == 0 ) { 
    // number is multiple of 3 ( after the first one ) - this works
    echo "alpha";
} else if (???????????????????????????????) {
    // show for 2, 5, 8, and so-on! 
    echo "omega";
}

// Later in the document
$myNumber++;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition you're looking for is:

```
} else if ($myNumber % 3 == 2) {
```

Incidentally, you don't need the `|| $myNumber == 0` on the first condition, as `0 % 3` is zero.

Comment: Excellent - That's is it exactly, thanks! so the `== 2` part sets the starting number. Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @colin Do you understand what the `%` operator is doing?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an offset calculation:

```
if (($i    ) % 3 == 0) { ... } // 0, 3, 6, 9, ...
if (($i - 1) % 3 == 0) { ... } // 1, 4, 7, 10, ...
if (($i - 2) % 3 == 0) { ... } // 2, 5, 8, 11, ...
```